# Simultaneously Ajax requests return the same result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script was making 2 simultaneous Ajax calls and I noticed I was getting the same results for each in the success callback, despite each page having entirely different content. This is what the initial script looked like:

```
function getData(url) {
    console.info(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var response = $(data);
            var $products = response.find("#results tr");
        }
    });
}

getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flower-bulb-sale")
getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/value-seed-varieties");
```

Checking the DevTools network tab, each request was indeed returning the content from the first request (http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flower-bulb-sale).

The first request (http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flower-bulb-sale) produces the correct result (it has that yellow flower as it's page content):
[image]

But the second request (http://www.thompson-morgan.com/value-seed-varieties) produces the result from the first request!:

[image]

The only thing that seemed to prevent this from happening was slightly staggering each call with a setTimeout as such:

```
setTimeout(function(){getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flower-bulb-sale")}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/value-seed-varieties")}, 1000);
```

[image]

Why would the second request return the content from the first request? Is there a way to get around this without having to use stagger the requests as I've done?

Comment: Sounds like a server-side issue to me. Fixing it client-side is going to be hacky at best.

Comment: could it be that $products is getting overwritten?  maybe consider using promises and promise.all()   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: @JonahWilliams nope. since the problem is present in the network tab.

Comment: Johah - $products is the same because the page result is the same. I'm wondering why I'm getting the same page despite 2 different requests to different locations.

Comment: why? because the output of those 2 locations is the same.

Comment: @charlietfl the output is not the same. You can see that by visiting the 2 urls.

Answer (score 0):

Change the above code to below.  Now we have a return value and can specify the location of the data using the .done() method

```
function getData(url) {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      async: true,
    });
}

getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/flower-bulb-sale")
  .done(function(res) {
      //do something with res
      var response = $(data);
      console.log(response.find("#results tr"));
  });
getData("http://www.thompson-morgan.com/value-seed-varieties")
  .done(function(res) {
            //do something with res
      var response = $(data);
      console.log(response.find("#results tr"));
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm limited in using jQuery v1.4.2 which does not support the done function.